# Updating Coordinator Layout Background From Java (Dynamically)

Tags: java, android

Im working on a weather app.
I have a coordinator layout in my main activty layout in which i have to update the background due to its condition(sunny,clear night and so on...).
I have been using the following code:
`coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewApp); 
 coordinatorLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sunny_day);`

it works alright for the first time that app runs but as i change the location, it gives me the force-stop error. i think the problem is because im updating the UI from the java(dynamically). So i tried using the following code instead and there was no force-stop anymore:

```
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    coordinatorLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sunny_day));
                }
            });
```

Now i have another problem!
when i run the app with the specific location like 'dallas' it works great and shows the background correctly. but when i search for another city like 'shanghai', since it has different weather conditions im expecting it to change the background, but the background changes for a second and immediately it gets back to the previous one!
here is my method which sets the background:

```
    private String setWeatherIcon(int actualId, int hourOfDay) {
    int id = actualId / 100;
    String icon = "";
    if (actualId == 800) {
        if (hourOfDay >= 7 && hourOfDay < 20) {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    coordinatorLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sunny_day));
                }
            });
            icon = this.getString(R.string.weather_sunny);

        } else {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    coordinatorLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sunny_day));
                }
            });
            icon = this.getString(R.string.weather_clear_night);
        }
    } else {
        switch (id) {
            case 2:
                icon = this.getString(R.string.weather_thunder);
                break;
            case 3:
                icon = this.getString(R.string.weather_drizzle);
                break;
            case 7:
                icon = this.getString(R.string.weather_foggy);
                break;
            case 8:
                icon = this.getString(R.string.weather_cloudy);
                break;
            case 6:
                icon = this.getString(R.string.weather_snowy);
                break;
            case 5:
                icon = this.getString(R.string.weather_rainy);
                break;
        }
    }
    return icon;
}
```

by the way i have implemented the first two conditions so far.
can someone give me a little hint on how this UI thread works?!

Comment: Did you tried debugging. it will help you understand the flow of your code. I am suspecting, you are continuously checking for location. it changes background for a sec and then again it set back for your current location.

Comment: @ashutiwari4 I found the problem! since it is loading the icon multiple times(forecasts) it shows the background which is set in the last call!

Comment: That is Awesome :)